# For Search In PHP using Ajax

Tags: php

I perform live search in php using ajax. This is my code for performing task
googleajax.php

```
<?php 

    $id=$_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $temp=$_POST['name'];echo $temp;
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getValue(id)
    {       


        var strURL="googledata.php?id="+id;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=req.responseText;                     
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);

        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
        <?php
            /*$query="Select * from tblcountry where country_id='".$id."'";
            echo $
            $res=mysql_query($res);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            {
                extract($row);*/
            ?>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onKeyUp="getValue(this.value)" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="serch">

    <div id="div1" name="div1">

    </div>

                <?php
            /*<!--}-->*/

        ?>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and googledata.php

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
    die("error in connection");
}
else
{
    mysql_select_db("hms2012",$con);
}
$id= $_GET['id'];
if($id=="")
{
}
else
{
    $result=mysql_query("select * from tblcountry where country_name like '$id%'");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        extract($row);

        echo "<option value='$country_id'><a href='googleajax.php?id=$country_id'>".$country_name."</a><br></option>";

    }

}
?>
```

Performing this code I can not select value for press key.
What was the use that I can select the value?

Comment: Yay! [SQL Injection!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) Good for you.

Comment: [MySQL and PHP (draft)](https://gist.github.com/2362466).

Answer (score 1):

You have no `<select></select>` around your `<options>` tags list.

You should take a look on using jQuery for your Ajax stuff.

Answer (score 0):

what is $country_id and $country_name. I have changed it by assumption. Please check.

```
    echo '<select name="somename">';    
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        extract($row);

    echo "<option value='".$row['country_id']."'><a href='googleajax.php?id=".$row['country_id']."'>".$row['country_name']."</a><br></option>";

    }
   echo "</select>";
```

Comment: how to select that data using arrow key on keyboard

Comment: Which data do you want to select?